# Blazor Web App on .net 8: adding Azure Entra Authentication does not work

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Visual Studio 2022 updated, all the latest workloads installed. I create Blazor Web App type of project with WebAssembly interactive render mode:

[image]

Now once the project got created, I try to add MS Identity Platform connected service, referencing Client project to my Azure Entra in "Connected Services". It fails with the error

[image]

It adds only Login and RedirectToLogin to a shared folder, none of the declared changes are done.

While I need WebAssembly type of authentication, I tried to connect to Entra from server project too, but it also failed.

Did anyone try and had a success? Just wanted to know if it's something wrong with my machine, or it's not supported yet.

Comment: Have you resolved this?   The error your getting for object reference not set to an instance of an object happens b/c user secrets isn't installed correctly via the connected services workflow.  If you 'Manage User Secrets' in the main project before you attempt to add msidentity, it will work correctly.   However, the template code is still incorrect and non-compliant with NET 8.   Let me know if you've found a fix.

Comment: no, it seems to be not yet properly supported in .net, waiting for updates

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the template is broken or at least squishy right now.
Anyways, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-microsoft-entra-id?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0) provides a working example

This cmd is the equivalent of the (broken?!) template you've used:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -au SingleOrg --api-client-id "{SERVER API APP CLIENT ID}" --app-id-uri "{SERVER API APP ID URI GUID}" --client-id "{CLIENT APP CLIENT ID}" --default-scope "{DEFAULT SCOPE}" --domain "{TENANT DOMAIN}" -ho -o {PROJECT NAME} --tenant-id "{TENANT ID}"
```

You will receive a .net7 project with a working Blazor App with Entra login. I was able to update it to .net8 without any problems and login was still working.